# Strange binary file format when writing integers on Windows

Tags: python, arrays, windows, binary, format

Just encounter a very unusual problem when I was trying to write integers to a file on Windows 7 (as well as Windows XP). The source code is as follows:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

def test_write(list_of_integers):
  fmt = '=' + ('L' * len(list_of_integers))
  with open('test.dat', 'wb') as f: f.write(pack(fmt, *list_of_integers))

num = [48, 1699505740, 1, 1, 13988, 13468, 2228, 51]
```

Here is the fun part. When I wrote the whole array to file, i.e.

```
test_write(num)
```

Using a Hex Editor, the file looks like:

```
Address   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
00000000  30  00  e6  99  8c  e6  95  8c  01  00  01  00  e3  9a  a4  00
00000010  e3  92  9c  00  e0  a2  b4  00  33  00
```

When only part of array was written, e.g.

```
test_write(num[:7])
```

the file looks like:

```
Address   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
00000000  30  00  00  00  4c  66  4c  65  01  00  00  00  01  00  00  00
00000010  a4  36  00  00  9c  34  00  00  b4  08  00  00
```

Interestingly enough, number can be read back from the file again using struct.unpack in both format.

Can anybody shed some light on the different formatting?

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your hex editor's output. Check the following: `binascii.hexlify(open('test.dat', 'rb').read())`. It should return `'300000004c664c650100000001000000a43600009c340000b408000033000000'`  (4 bytes, or 8 hex digits, per little-endian integer).

Comment: @eryksun, you're probably right. I've uploaded both files to a linux server to check them using hexdump. It seems no such problem! What a bug of the hex editor!